# How do I make a scoreboard command that detects when a player crouches in multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.13/1.14, I start with some commands that work for singleplayer like:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Sneak minecraft.custom:minecraft.sneak_time
/execute as @a[scores={Sneak=1..}] at (my name) run effect give (my name) minecraft:jump_boost 1 2 true
/scoreboard players reset @a[scores={Sneak=1..}] Sneak
```

I've already tested it on a multiplayer server and it doesn't appear to work. I then tried adding a tag:

```
/execute as @a[name=(my name),scores={Sneak=1..}] at Dashinglizard run effect give Dashinglizard minecraft:jump_boost 1 2 true
```

and it still didn't work.

[image: I do building, so I'm not very good at commands]

Comment: I'm off topic but, why is there a picture of a tree?

Comment: I don't really know, I just added it

Answer (score 1):

It's a actually a really simple syntax mistake. Here it is the corrected version:

```
/execute as @a[scores={Sneak=1..}] run effect give @s minecraft:jump_boost 1 2 true
```

Your previous command would add the jump boost effect to *you* if there was anyone else, including you, crouching.

Using @s will refer to a previous entity. In this case, the @s in `effect give @s` refers to `@a[scores={Sneak=1..}]` which means it will give the effect to any, and only, player that has those specifications.

As a side note, `at (your name)` or `at @e` (or any variatons of it) will execute using this entity coordinate, thus being useless as this does not require any coordinate at all.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that it only detects for when I crouch, and only affects me with jump boost - and not for other players?

Comment: Yes. `/execute as @e[name=Dashinglizard,scores={Sneak=1..}] run effect give @s minecraft:jump_boost 1 2 true`